# How can kon-boot run code in UEFI?

Tags: rootkits, uefi, secure-boot

I've now googled a lot, but the only information I can find is 'kon-boot hides its code in BIOS memory and changes kernel-code on the fly'...

As far as I understand, UEFI initializes devices and tries to load bootloaders into memory from MBRs. Now if Kon-Boot only manipulated bootloaders, then it wouldn't work in combination with the SecureBoot option in UEFI, as this would identify the manipulated bootloader/kernel - that's why it has to run in BIOS/UEFI memory directly. But how is that achieved?

How is Kon-Boot code copied to UEFI, which functionality is used here where UEFI would load arbitrary code into its own memory that also would get executed at a certain point?

Comment: You saw this? https://kon-boot.com/docs/windows_guide/

Comment: yes, but it does not answer the question

Comment: And this? https://www.cert-ist.com/public/en/SO_detail?code=bootkits#:~:text=the%20previous%20paragraph.-,Technical%20details,-The%20source%20code

Comment: No, not one single word about secureboot... I could also ask the question in a different way: How can you manipulate the BIOS/UEFI memory? I understand it that the 0x13 interrupt would load the bootloader from the MBR, but that one is protected via SecureBoot, so no way to use that interrupt to inject the code.

Comment: ... you didn't read the Kon Boot link about Secure Boot ...

Comment: Your question appears to be all over the place. Are you asking how Kon Boot works if SecureBoot is enabled? That's hinted at in the official documentation. Are you asking how Kon Boot works in general? That's provided by the historical link. But you appear to jump around what you want to know, or you are conflating concepts together that can't be answered as a single concept.

Comment: I did read all the links you have provided but obviously I didn't find what I was looking for. Turns out that I always assumed that Kon-Boot can bypass SecureBoot in any case but obviously it can't. Voting down only on that fact is not really fair.

Comment: But if you did not read the official documentation, which explains what you needed to know, then that falls under the downvote reason of "does not show research effort". And then to reject the official documentation once it is pointed out to you, definitely deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No bypass of SecureBoot is done. The product states in the system requirements that enabled SecureBoot is not supported:

> **Not supported**: Disk encryption, tablets (includes Microsoft Surface hybrid), **enabled SecureBoot** , multiple operating systems installed on target computer, kernel debuggers, enabled secure boot, enabled virtualization (VMware, QEMU, VirtualBox, etc.), authorization through domain. CD and Floppy versions are deprecated (but still in the package for compatibility reasons).

Comment: Yes, the product since 3.5 has a Secure Boot bypass feature that they say works sometimes. And they explain that it uses keys (that have been since been revoked in updated BIOS)

Comment: oh wow. I was too much focused on the wikipedia-articles which say that it can bypass secureboot from 3.5 on, but I didn't know that it's not supported (everywhere) and may not work depending on your UEFI). So now it's clear: Kon-Boot gets loaded via MBR and then modifies the bootloader/kernel. I originally thought it would directly inject itself into the UEFI/BIOS memory/code and do the manipulation "from there"...

Comment: @BlackFlag Read official documentation not wiki articles as your primary source.